# Report to tell how long it took from order to shipping

Tags: shipping, reports, ee-1.14.2.4

I am trying to find out if there is a **report** to show how long (how many days) it took for **orders** to be **shipped**.

For instance, for July the average lapse from **order** to **shipping** was 2 days etc.

Answer (score 3):

This report does not exist out-of-the-box per-se, but you can get this information with an SQL query *[insert standard caution about running SQL on your live production database]*:

## SQL Query

```
select e.increment_id,e.created_at as order_date, min(sfs.created_at) as first_shipment_date, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, e.created_at, sfs.created_at) as time_to_shipment
from sales_flat_order e
left join sales_flat_shipment sfs on (e.entity_id = sfs.order_id)
group by e.created_at having (time_to_shipment is not null)
order by e.created_at desc
```

## Sample output

```
increment_id    order_date  first_shipment_date time_to_shipment
38660   2017-08-16 17:38:00 2017-08-16 19:43:22 2
38659   2017-08-16 16:51:31 2017-08-16 19:48:56 2
38658   2017-08-16 16:42:34 2017-08-16 17:13:51 0
38657   2017-08-16 14:35:48 2017-08-16 15:23:19 0
38656   2017-08-16 14:10:33 2017-08-16 15:22:16 1
```